# How to create slanting text inside a chart

Tags: tableau-api

I need to create a slanting text inside a bar chart or donut chart.

Currently Tableau supports only text in vertical and horizontal directions.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Tableau doesn't provide support for slanting text, just vertical and horizontal.

Comment: Please don't. Slanting text is always much harder to read than horizontal text. You are better off redesigning your view so it doesn't need slanted text (use tooltips to identify segments, for example). And don't do donut charts either: they are a dataviz abomination like pie charts with brass knobs on.